# Encountered NoMethodError when binding two table data in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have established an association between three models, where User can `has_many` Recipe, and Recipe `belongs_to` User. This is what the model sets:

model User

```
has_many :reviews
has_many :recipes, through: :reviews
```

model Recipe

```
has_many :reviews
has_many :users
belongs_to :user
```

model Review

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipe
```

Currently, User and Recipe each have a data. I want to assign Recipe to User, so I did the following in the Rails console:

```
u2 = User.find_by_id(2)
r1 = Recipe.find_by_id(1)
u2.recipes = r1
```

Then "NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #Recipe:0x0000560632fde3d0)" appears.

I can't understand, `has_many` or `has_one` should generate `recipes` and `recipes=` methods, why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work since you're attempting to assign a single record to a `has_many` assocation. The reason you're getting `undefined method 'each'` is that the generated setter expects an array or a an assocation that can be iterated upon. For example:

```
user = User.find(2)
user.recipies = Recipe.where(id: 1)
```

But the idiomatically correct way to assign a single record to a `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` assocation is with the shovel method:

```
u2 = User.find_by_id(2)
r1 = Recipe.find_by_id(1)
u2.recipes << r1
```

With an indirect assiation Rails will implicitly create the rows in the join table.